# Какие есть работающие платежные системы с API

Tags: платежи, поиск-api

Разрабатываю веб-приложение, но есть желание добавить платёжную систему на продаваемые продукты. Многие сервисы уже перестали работать в России. Нужны такие платёжные системы, которые бы обслуживались в России, имели API для интеграции со своим сервисом и обслуживали физических лиц. Многие работают только с юридическими лицами, что является проблемно. Многие просмотрел, регистрировался, но по итогу требуют документы, которых нет у физического лица.

Comment: *"по итогу требуют документы, которых нет у физического лица"* - есть сомнения, что физик может подобным заниматься, без образования хотя бы ИП или ПБОЮЛ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После дополнительных поисков нашёл единственную систему - FreeKassa. Был вариант ещё Qiwi, но он приостановил выдачу ключей.